# Create form for domain object with multiselect Enum field fails with 'Property xxx is type-mismatched'

Tags: grails, enums, grails-4

I am using Grails 4.0.4 w/ GORM 7.0.7.RELEASE
The database I am using is MongoDB

I can successfully run the application and navigate to the create form for the domain class. I can select the value for the singleton field `someOtherEnum`. I can multiselect values for the `categories` field. When I submit the form, however, I get this message: 'Property categories is type-mismatched'. I used this approach based on the answers to another question posted here, but it's not working for me. I am not using an embedded enum or `hasMany` collection like that user.

The controller and service were generated by the `generate-all` command.

[How to add a multiple enum field to the create and edit forms in Grails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61593017/how-to-add-a-multiple-enum-field-to-the-create-and-edit-forms-in-grails-4)

I have an enum located in `src/main/groovy/com/project/core/dsl` I am using to populate a multiselect field for a domain class:

```
package com.project.core.dsl

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
enum Category {
   CATEGORY_ONE("Category One"),
   CATEGORY_TWO("Category Two"),
   CATEGORY_THREE("Category Three")

   private final String id

   private Category(String id) { this.id = id }

   @Override
   String toString() { id }

   String getKey() { name() }
}
```

The domain class:

```
package com.project.core

import com.project.core.dsl.SomeOtherEnum
import com.project.core.dsl.Category

class DomainObject {

    SomeOtherEnum someOtherEnum
    Set<Category> categories

    static constraints = {
    }

    static mapping = {
        someOtherEnum index: true
    }

    @Override
    String toString() {
        return "DomainObject{" +
            "someOtherEnum=" + someOtherEnum +
            ", categories=" + categories +
            '}';
    }
}
```

In the `create.gsp` view, I have this form:

```
<g:form resource="${this.domainObject}" method="POST">
    <fieldset class="form">
        <f:with bean="domainObject">
            <f:field property="someOtherEnum"/>
            <f:field property="categories">
                <g:select
                    multiple="true"
                    name="${property}"
                    from="${Category}"
                    value="${domainObject?.categories}"
                />
            </f:field>
        </f:with>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="buttons">
        <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
    </fieldset>
</g:form>
```

The domain class Controller:

```
package com.project.core

import grails.validation.ValidationException
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*

class DomainObject {

    DomainObjectService domainObjectService

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond domainObjectService.list(params), model:[domainObjectCount: domainObjectService.count()]
    }

    def show(Long id) {
        respond domainObjectService.get(id)
    }

    def create() {
        respond new DomainObject(params)
    }

    def save(DomainObject domainObject) {
        if (domainObject == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        try {
            domainObjectService.save(domainObject)
        } catch (ValidationException e) {
            respond domainObject.errors, view:'create'
            return
        }

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'domainObject.label', default: 'DomainObject'), domainObject.id])
                redirect domainObject
            }
            '*' { respond domainObject, [status: CREATED] }
        }
    }

    def edit(Long id) {
        respond domainObjectService.get(id)
    }

    def update(DomainObject domainObject) {
        if (domainObject == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        try {
            domainObjectService.save(domainObject)
        } catch (ValidationException e) {
            respond domainObject.errors, view:'edit'
            return
        }

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'domainObject.label', default: 'DomainObject'), domainObject.id])
                redirect domainObject
            }
            '*'{ respond domainObject, [status: OK] }
        }
    }

    def delete(Long id) {
        if (id == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        domainObjectService.delete(id)

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'domainObject.label', default: 'DomainObject'), id])
                redirect action:"index", method:"GET"
            }
            '*'{ render status: NO_CONTENT }
        }
    }

    protected void notFound() {
        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'domainObject.label', default: 'DomainObject'), params.id])
                redirect action: "index", method: "GET"
            }
            '*'{ render status: NOT_FOUND }
        }
    }
}
```

The domain object service:

```
package com.project.core

import grails.gorm.services.Service

@Service(DomainObject)
interface DomainObjectService {

    DomainObject get(Serializable id)

    List<DomainObject> list(Map args)

    Long count()

    void delete(Serializable id)

    DomainObject save(DomainObject domainObject)

}
```

Comment: Is that form posting to a controller action which uses the built in data binder to populate properties of the `DomainObject` instance?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown The controller is just the generated controller you get when using generate-all. Do I need to do something to the Controller class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get past my error by making the following changes. I added a hasMany statement in `DomainObject`

```
static hasMany = [categories: Category]
```

and I made these changes in the `create.gsp` file:

```
<f:field property="categories">
    <g:select
         multiple="true"
         name="${property}"
         from="${Category?.values()}"
         optionKey="key"
         value="${domainObject?.categories}"
    />
</f:field>
```